# Having problems after getting random document in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
function randomSpam(){
    MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        const dbo = db.db("database0");
        dbo.collection("spams").aggregate([{ $sample: { size:1, } }]).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            db.close();
             });  
          });
       }
```

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxnbN.png)

As you can see above I managed to get a random document, now my question is : How can I access a field of the random document I have got? Thanks. (in this case the field named "link, check console output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result[0].link
```

is what you want — the 0 refers to the first document, and the `link` refers to the field.

Answer (score 0):

You can try, it should work:

```
 result[0].link
```